# Duplicating the result when adding two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, duplicates

I'm working on a website with categories. When the user clicks a link it goes to `categories.php?id=$id`

This is working.  Since I'm using FK, I have to use this code:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM post_posts, post_cat WHERE post_cat = $id" )
or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['idpost_posts']=$row['idpost_posts'];

        echo '<div id="single-post" class="slidingDiv">
            <div id="title">' . $row['post_header'] . '</div>
            <div id="image"><img src="' . $row['post_thumb'] . '" width="300" height="200"></div>
            <div id="text">' . substr($row['post_content'], 0, 500) . '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['idpost_posts'] . '"> Les mer...</a>' . '      </div>
            <div id="author">' . "Skrevet: " . date('j. F Y ', strtotime($row['post_date'])) . ' | <a href="user.php?id=' . $row['idpost_users'] . '">' . $row['user_name'] . '</a></div> 
            <div id="post-divider"></div>
            </div>';
    }    
}
```

The code is working, but as I stated earlier, it shows the same row 5 times. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
THis is what i'm using now, and it shows only two rows now, which is better:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT idpost_posts, post_content, post_header, post_thumb, post_date, idpost_users, user_name FROM post_posts, post_cat, post_users WHERE post_cat = $id" )
        or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);if ($result) {while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['idpost_posts']=$row['idpost_posts'];

        echo '<div id="single-post" class="slidingDiv">
            <div id="title">' . $row['post_header'] . '</div>
            <div id="image"><img src="' . $row['post_thumb'] . '" width="300" height="200"></div>
            <div id="text">' . substr($row['post_content'], 0, 500) . '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['idpost_posts'] . '"> Les mer...</a>' . '      </div>
            <div id="author">' . "Skrevet: " . date('j. F Y ', strtotime($row['post_date'])) . ' | <a href="user.php?id=' . $row['idpost_users'] . '">' . $row['user_name'] . '</a></div> 
            <div id="post-divider"></div>
            </div>';
```

Comment: make your query `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Write your query with `INNER JOIN`

Comment: please tell me that you are searching for sql injection in $id. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL "SELECT * FROM post_posts, post_cat WHERE post_cat = $id" is performing a cross Cartesian join(YOU DO NOT WANT THIS) between the post_posts and the post_cat table.  You should be defining which columns it should be joining the two table together like so.

```
SELECT * FROM post_posts, post_cat WHERE post_posts.<primary key col name> = post_cat.<foreign key col name> AND post_cat = $id
```

where you are replacing the <> with the columns that define the foreign key relationship in each table.  If you want more detailed help you need to post the foreign key constraint details including the column it is applied to and the column it references in the other table.

Comment: This may just be the behavior of your data. I advise correctly joining and using the previously specified DISTINCT. This will give you the most efficent query while only returning one row.

Answer (score 1):

Change this
 `

```
   $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM post_posts, post_cat WHERE post_cat = $id" )
```

`To this:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM post_posts, post_cat WHERE post_cat = $id" )
```

Comment: you probably have to use `SELECT DISTINCT ` then the specific fields you're going to use instead of using *...so like `SELECT DISTINCT user_name, idpost_posts,` etc

Comment: @StianInstebo What do you mean by select xx from `table` where `table= value` ?!

Comment: i've changed my script look in the OP

Comment: by that i mean that it will only show the rows with categorie = id (id of category items)

Comment: is `post_cat` the name of a column or a table? because I think you are confusing the two.

Comment: it's the name of the table

Comment: So how can a whole table equal to the `id`in you `where` clause?

Comment: it's ided by cat id 1 = all id 2 = others and so on